# I'm runing HECV-SCM encoder with scc cfg file but it can't output IDR frame

Tags: video-processing, video-encoding, yuv, hevc, h.265

The version I used is HM-16.16+SCM-8.5 and use

```
./TAppEncoderStatic -c ../cfg/encoder_intra_main_scc.cfg -c ../cfg/per-sequence/Desktop_420.cfg  -i ../../yuv/bridge-close_qcif.yuv -b wstr.bin -o wrec.yuv -wdt 176 -hgt 144 --SummaryPicFilenameBase true --SummaryVerboseness true -f 60
```

the inputfile is yuv420P format、 8bit depth and resolution 176x144

the output message

```
SUMMARY --------------------------------------------------------
            Total Frames |   Bitrate     Y-PSNR    U-PSNR    V-PSNR    YUV-PSNR  Y-MSE     U-MSE     V-MSE    YUV-MSE 
Average:           60    a     951.9920   33.4138   36.9571   37.5667   34.3583   29.6307   13.1079   11.3920   23.8371
From MSE:          60    a     951.9920   33.4134   36.9555   37.5648   34.3583


I Slices--------------------------------------------------------
            Total Frames |   Bitrate     Y-PSNR    U-PSNR    V-PSNR    YUV-PSNR  Y-MSE     U-MSE     V-MSE    YUV-MSE 
Average:            0    i         -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan
From MSE:           0    i         -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan


P Slices--------------------------------------------------------
            Total Frames |   Bitrate     Y-PSNR    U-PSNR    V-PSNR    YUV-PSNR  Y-MSE     U-MSE     V-MSE    YUV-MSE 
Average:           60    p     951.9920   33.4138   36.9571   37.5667   34.3583   29.6307   13.1079   11.3920   23.8371
From MSE:          60    p     951.9920   33.4134   36.9555   37.5648   34.3583


B Slices--------------------------------------------------------
            Total Frames |   Bitrate     Y-PSNR    U-PSNR    V-PSNR    YUV-PSNR  Y-MSE     U-MSE     V-MSE    YUV-MSE 
Average:            0    b         -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan
From MSE:           0    b         -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan

RVM: 0.000
Bytes written to file: 118999 (951.992 kbps)
Bytes for SPS/PPS/Slice (Incl. Annex B): 118999 (951.992 kbps)

 Total Time:       37.247 sec.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your bitstream wstr.bin decodable?

Comment: Thanks. The output file can be decode and if set IntraBlockCopyEnable to 1 I can get the IDR frame